# processing and open CV

Tags: opencv, arduino, processing, libraries

I have processing 2.0 software and openCV 2.4.6.1, how and where do i add the openCV libraries into my processing software?. I intend to make a motor run based on face detection. I havent found any kind of proper documentation that explains the procedure of adding the files.

Comment: I have openCV 2.4.9 also